# Keep sub-menu displayed on page refresh with sessionStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, wordpress

I'm relatively new to javascript & jQuery.

I'm developing a site in WordPress with a nav-menu in the header with 4 parent selections and sub-menus appearing when you click on each parent. The issue is when selecting a parent menu the webpage changes to another landing page and my sub-menu then disappears but needs to be there all the time.

I have researched this for weeks and feel I've got close to the answer but can't fathom the final bit, I'm trying to use sessionStorage to retain the value of the menu, but once I Parse it with JSON nothing happens.

(I understand that the current IF statement also won't return true, but got stuck at the JSON part before knowing what to code there!)

```
var menuItem;

$('#primary-menu > li > a').click(function(e){


     menuItem = $(this).siblings();
     console.log(menuItem);

     sessionStorage.setItem('clicked', JSON.stringify(menuItem));


  $(menuItem).slideDown();

});



$(document).ready(function(){


     var clicked = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('clicked'));


        console.log(clicked);
    if (clicked === 'true') {

        $(clicked).show();

        }

});
```